# Is "The two men Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill were . . . " grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, syntax

In a [blog](http://mashable.com/2016/03/22/savchenko-trial-sentence/#cSL8s0nZUOqa), I read the following sentence:

> The two men Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

I can only understand that it says something about two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk, but I feel that the sentence looks weird. Is it grammatical or not? What can we write in simple language for this sentence?

Can I write above sentence in the following way?

> Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

Comment: It's grammatical, but it's a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)

Comment: It grammatically correct but awkward. Your rephrasing is clearer.

Comment: This sentence is a travesty.

Comment: The first sentence is correct but awkward. The rephrasing is easier to parse, but it has slightly different emphasis. The first sentence draws attention to the identity of the victims (_The two men [who were killed] were A.V. and I.K._, with the rest of the sentence providing additional information) while the second feels like it stresses the crime itself (_The crime Savchenko was convicted of was [...]_, again with some extra information).

Answer (score 24):

The sentence is difficult to parse because it has a long relative clause with no *wh*-word. In addition, the relative clause has an extra phrase in the middle. It may help to think about the sentence like this:

- The two men were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

Now we may not know who these *two men* are.  We could use a relative clause to explain this:

- The two men [who Savenko was convicted of helping to kill] were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

This relative clause has a gap at the end. We understand the gap as referring to the two men. So the sentence can be modeled like this:

- The two men [who Savenko was convicted of helping to kill <s>them</s>] were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

We might want to give some extra information about Savenko. For example we could show that he was an Iraq war veteran:

- The two men who Savenko [an Iraq war veteran]  was convicted of helping to kill  were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

In the Original example, the word *who* is missing. This is because we don't need to use *who* if it is not the Subject of the relative clause.

**The Original Poster's second question**

> Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The sentence above gives us the same information as the original example. However, the information is arranged in a different way. In the original text, it sounds as if they already told us that Savachenko was convicted of killing two men. If we used the Original Poster's (OP's) sentence in this situation it would sound a bit odd. Compare these two pairs of sentences.

- Savenko was convicted yesterday of helping to kill two men. Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.
- Savenko was convicted yesterday of helping to kill two men. The two men who Savenko, an Iraq war veteran,  was convicted of helping to kill  were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The second pair is better, because it makes the two men from the first sentence into the Subject of the second sentence. We like to organise our writing like this. In the first pair of sentences, the second sentence seems to be too similar to the first one.

Comment: Should the actual steps include "whom" instead of "who"?  e.g. The two men [whom Savenko was convicted of helping to kill] were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

Comment: @Keeta: that would certainly be correct, and would be preferred by some styles.

Comment: @Keeta Yes, *whom* is another option here. In modern English we can use either *who* or *whom* here. :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Oxford Dictionaries state: "...[I]f you are writing at work, at college or university, or for publication, it is ... advisable to use the more formal whom, especially in constructions with a preposition."  This item certainly looks to meet at least one of these criteria. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/who-or-whom-american

Comment: @Keeta We have no choice when *whom* is the complement of a preposition. However, in all other circumstances it is entirely optional. If you want to sound extremely formal in your university writing then go ahead and use *whom*. However, I've never seen a uni paper corrected for *who* (apart from after  a preposition)- and in terms of blogs, this level of formality is certainly not required.

Comment: Too complex to understand for a non-native speaker!

Comment: @RuchirM I'm sorry. I've written a different type of answer for you below. Is it more helpful for you?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The Original Poster, Ruchir, asks if the sentence above can be used as a version of the complicated sentence from the blog. It can. It has  the same information, but the information is organised in a different way. The focus of the sentence is  different. We can use the Original Poster's example to help us understand the example from the blog.

Look at the following conversation. It is a bit unusual because the speakers are using full sentences instead of short answers:

> > **A**: Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.
> >
> > **B**: Sorry? *Who* are the two men Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill?
> >
> > **A**: The two men Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The last sentence here is the original example from the blog. We can see that the focus of the two sentences is different. The first sentence tells us what happened to Savchenko. The last sentence tells us who the two victims were.

Comment: Yes, this simply clarifies my doubts. +1 for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to write

> Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

it is *fine*. I'd prefer a little change though!

> Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men *named/called* Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

About the original sentence, it is just *a style* of writing.

Replace names, make a sentence shorter

> The two men Ruchir, an Indian, was talking about were JR and StoneyB!

I'm not sure but a little comma may help

> The two men, Ruchir, an Indian, was talking about were JR and StoneyB!

**The *hint* is 'was' applies to 'Ruchir' and 'were' to those both men!**

Comment: It clarifies everything. I always want a simple explanation for my questions on this platform. Spot on, as always!

Comment: I think the extra comma in your last example sentence makes the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: I think so too, @DamkerngT.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is hard to parse. The second is much easier to understand, and we can deduct the same information from both. But I would use each (with a "who" inserted in the first one) in different ways:

Their identity was kept a secret, but today we were told that the two men (, whom) Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill (,) were Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The inmates of the prison were all there for very serious crimes. For example, Savchenko, an Iraq war veteran, was convicted of helping to kill the two men Anton Voloshin and Igor Kornelyuk.

The first sentence emphasizes the names of the two men, the second emphasizes the evil act and the conviction.